# How to send and receive mutlicast in iOS using different ports

Tags: ios, swift, multicast

I do have a Hardware device which receives the data at port 1235 and sending at port 1234.

Now the iOS app has to listen to port 1234 and if send the data to 1235.

Following the guidance from Apple, I've implemented a quick multicast group.

Code for starting the group:

```
let multicast = try! NWMulticastGroup(for: [.hostPort(host: "224.0.0.1", port: 1234)])
group = NWConnectionGroup(with: multicast, using: .udp)

group?.setReceiveHandler(maximumMessageSize: 128) { message, data, b in
        log("‍ Received message:")
}
group?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
    print("Group entered state \(String(describing: newState))")
}
group?.start(queue: .global())
```

Everything works fine when receiving data in iOS from the external device, but the quest is, how I can use the newly created group to send data from iOS to the external device? Especially if its using a different port, other than the one its listening to?

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the apple docs,

```
let groupSendContent = Data("helloAll".utf8)
group.send(content: groupSendContent) { (error)
    print("Send complete with error \(String(describing: error))")
}
```

When you are done make sure to cancel and clean up.

```
group.cancel()
```

EDIT---
It sounds like you want your port number to be dynamic. In that case you will have to create a variable and change the value to what port you need.

```
let multicast = try! NWMulticastGroup(for: [.hostPort(host: "224.0.0.1", port: portVariable)])
```

when you want to send to a different port simply change the `portVariable` and establish a new connection.

```
portVariable = 12345

let multicast = try! NWMulticastGroup(for: [.hostPort(host: "224.0.0.1", port: portVariable)])
```

and then send with code above

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick question though, if we use group, will it not send it to port 1234? In our case the External device is listening for requests on port 1235.

Comment: @VadimSalajan it sounds like you want it to be dynamic. you will have to create a variable instead in its place.

Comment: Tried this approach, I think its close to resolving the problem. But now I'm getting "address in use" whenever I'm create the 2nd multicastt. Even calling `cancel` on the previous group doesn't help.